# Why do we sleep?

Tags: sleep, mental-health, brain, sleep-cycles, sleep-deprivation

I was reading many things about sleep. But I am very curious about knowing why do we sleep. Is it only for trashing out toxic materials or is it anything else?

Comment: The English Wikipedia entry _Sleep_  has a section _Functions of sleep_ . Could you please edit your question and add, in what way this article does or does not answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleep?wprov=sfla1

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because sleep is a biological function so should be asked on biology.se